# Android RAM strange allocation

Tags: java, android, memory-management, memory-leaks, ram

I'm tracing my android application RAM usage.

When it starts it allocates **9mb** ram before launcher activity's `onCreate()` is called. 
I traced using Android Device Monitor and looked at *heap allocations*.
It seems that **6mb** is just 
`1-byte array`. But in my application I do not use any byte array.

*Also Allocation* tracker shows that, this byte array was allocated at `dalvik.system.NativeStart.run`.

**P.S**
 I  searched for common bugs, I'm not having static initialized objects that may cause memory leak. I'm having many static String constants but I think that mustn't be the problem.

Comment: Some of the allocations the tracker reports are made by the Dalvik VM itself and the Android Framework, even before you `Activity` is created.

Comment: And is this my fault? Can i reduce that allocation? 
I fear 9 mb is just too much.

Comment: No, this is not your fault. Why do you think 9 mb is too much? Have you looked at memory usage of other apps running on your phone?

Comment: Maybe you're right , I'm writing SMS application and I compared to default SMS app , that uses 24 mb avarage. Mine uses 13-14mb. Maybe that's normal. Thank you!